jquery animation - shapes moving in linear motion
I want the shapes to reappear from the right as soon as they start to disappear on the left. For example, if I have square1, circle1, and star1 in a row moving from right to left, as soon as square1 begins to disappear on the left, it should immediately reappear on the right, without waiting for circle1 or star1 to disappear. I want to implement this using jquery.
function startAutoScroll() {
        const $track = $('.track');
        const $shapes = $('.shapes');
        const trackWidth = $track.width();
        const containerWidth = $('.track-container').width();
        const shapeWidth = $shapes.first().outerWidth(true); // Width including margin
    
        // Speed of scrolling based on slider value
        const scrollSpeed = 1; // Adjust as necessary for smoother scrolling
    
        // Continuous scrolling of the track
        autoScrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if (!isHovering) {
                let currentLeft = parseInt($track.css('left'), 10);
                let newLeft = currentLeft - scrollSpeed;
    
                // Reset track position to create a continuous effect
                if (Math.abs(newLeft) >= trackWidth) {
                    newLeft = 0;
                }
    
                $track.css('left', `${newLeft}px`);
            }
        }, 100 / autoScrollSpeed); // Interval time for smooth scrolling
    
        // Animate shapes with seamless looping
        function animateShapes() {
            const totalShapesWidth = $shapes.length * shapeWidth;
    
            // Position shapes outside the container initially
            $shapes.each(function(index) {
                $(this).css('left', containerWidth + index * shapeWidth + 'px');
            });
    
            // Animate shapes
            $({ offset: containerWidth }).animate(
                { offset: -totalShapesWidth },
                {
                    duration: 10000 / autoScrollSpeed, // Adjust duration based on speed
                    easing: 'linear',
                    step: function(now) {
                        $shapes.each(function(index) {
                            let offset = now + index * shapeWidth;
                            // Ensure the shapes wrap around seamlessly
                            if (offset <= -shapeWidth) {
                                offset += totalShapesWidth;
                            }
                            $(this).css('left', offset + 'px');
                        });
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        // Ensure the animation loops correctly
                        animateShapes(); // Loop animation
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    
        animateShapes(); // Start shape animation
    }


What code have you written? Are the shapes rendered to a canvas, or are they images?

they are svg's. you can find the code above

OK, we see your code.  Does it work?  What problem are you trying to solve?

so what is happening currently is i have multiple shapes, they are moving from right to left. so as soon as the first shapes starts to disappear i want the same shape to start appearing from the right without waiting for all the shapes to disappear first and then start to appear from right one by one.

Maybe this help: CSS animation jumps instead of infinite loop

@ShahramAlemzadeh yes this is exactly i want

I am not sure if this can be done with jQuery.fn.animate(). I tried this, but it kept all of the SVGs together and restarted only after the first one reached the end of its container.
You could design a jQuery plugin (see below) that mimics a game loop that sets the initial positions, and then repeatedly updates/renders after each animation frame.
Each SVG independently controls its position.


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.marquee').svgMarquee({ speed: 2, gap: 100 });
});

(function($) {
  const defaultOptions = { speed: 1, gap: 0 };

  $.fn.svgMarquee = function(options) {
    const settings = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      const $marquee = $(this);
      const $svgs = $marquee.find('svg');
      const xMax = $marquee.width();
      let xOffset = 0;

      $svgs.each(function() {
        const $svg = $(this);
        $svg.css('xOffset', xOffset).data('xOffset', xOffset);
        xOffset += $svg[0].getBBox().width + settings.gap;
      });

      function updatePositions() {
        $svgs.each(function() {
          const $svg = $(this);
          const xOffset = $svg.data('xOffset');
          $svg.data('xOffset', Math.floor(xOffset + settings.speed) % xMax);
        });
      }

      function applyPositions() {
        $svgs.each(function() {
          const $svg = $(this);
          $svg.css('left', $svg.data('xOffset'));
        });
      }

      function animate() {
        updatePositions();
        applyPositions();
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }

      animate();
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
.marquee {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.marquee svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marquee">
  <svg width="50" height="50" class="square">
    <rect width="50" height="50" fill="red" />
  </svg>
  <svg width="50" height="50" class="circle">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="blue" />
  </svg>
  <svg width="50" height="50" class="star" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <polygon points="12,2 15,8.9 22,9.3 17,14.3 18.2,21.2 12,17.7 5.8,21.2 7,14.3 2,9.3 9,8.9" fill="yellow" />
  </svg>
</div>




Cloning the items would make up for a better effect, instead of popping shapes (on the left) IMHO.

Could you please explain it with a example, if its not too much for you. Thank you in advance
